# Using PHP to save from textarea to db

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

I have a post form with a text area in it. When I save the text from my `textarea` into mysql db, the text is saved with some white spaces before and after my actual test.

Why is happening this? How can I overcome this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey, can you please paste the corresponding code in here?

Comment: Let me guess, you have whitespace between `<textarea></textarea>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably whitespace in your markup. For example:

```
<textarea>
    <?php echo ($textareavalue); ?>
</textarea>
```

You could either remove the whitespace

```
<textarea><?php echo ($textareavalue); ?></textarea>
```

Or you could trim() the input before storing it to the database

```
$_POST ['textareavalue'] = trim ($_POST ['textareavalue']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have code like this:

```
<textarea name="foobar">
  <? echo $contents; ?>
</textarea>
```

Then you are adding whitespace to the value before/after the `<? ... ?>` tags (note, php does try to remove whitespace in some situations, so sometimes you can get away with it).

The fix is to do this:

```
<textarea name="foobar"><? echo $contents; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted as it's a perfectly valid answer.  However, I'd advise against using short tags.

Comment: Yeah, I've never used short tags either. But in this case I think it makes the example clearer. 2 up votes and 2 down votes... no idea why!

Answer (score 0):

you can use trim function before inserting into database for perticular that post data...

```
$text_area = trim($_POST['text_area']);
```

it will remove spaces from begining and end of the string...